# mysql multiple AND condition on same column

Tags: php, mysql

i need a little complex query i have three tables  **tbl_users, tbl_employer_premium_services, tbl_premium_services** i have a scenario that i need those user who have bought **Preferred Candidate** and **Professional CV Writing** whose payment status is paid but i can't make two conditions on one column if any one have any idea about that kindly guide me my query is as follow

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.* 
FROM tbl_users as u, 
tbl_employer_premium_services as eps, 
tbl_premium_services as ps 
WHERE eps.fld_user_id = u.fld_id 
and (eps.fld_premium_service_id = ps.fld_id 
    AND ps.fld_name = 'Preferred Candidate'
    AND eps.fld_payment_status='Paid')
```

its working on one ps.fld_name condition but not on both i need those user who bought **Preferred Candidate** and **Professional CV Writing** services kindly help if any one has idea

Answer (score 0):

Use nested query instead of multiple AND conditions.

Edit: If you want to force two different values on a single field you shouldn't be using 'OR' instead of 'AND'?

Comment: i also tried on nested queries can you give me some idea about that

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT u.* 
FROM tbl_users as u, 
tbl_employer_premium_services as eps, 
tbl_premium_services as ps 
WHERE eps.fld_user_id = u.fld_id 
and (eps.fld_premium_service_id = ps.fld_id
    AND eps.fld_payment_status='Paid' AND ps.fld_name in (select fld_name from tbl_premium_services where fld_name='Preferred Candidate' OR fld_name = 'Professional CV Writing'))

Comment: in **OR** condition it also pick those users who have bought any one of the two services i need those users who bought both services at a time

Comment: fld_name is a compound attribute?!

Comment: no tbl_premium_services.fld_id is used a foreign key of tbl_employer_premium_services.fld_premium_service_id

Comment: provide your schema here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is due to the my english or not, but I fear I don't really understand your question.

Are you trying to put something like

```
ps.fld_name = 'Preferred Candidate' AND ps.fld_name = 'Professional CV Writing'
```

??

If so, it is clearly impossible. How can a field have 2 values ?

Comment: yes i want this but its not possible thats why i posted the question i tried on nested queries but its not going to an end

Comment: So I think you can use a junction table containing some Ids, for example :

User_id, fld_id, fld_payment_status

Comment: tbl_employer_premium_services works as a junction table